Recuction from 3-SAT
Why do we always try to reduce from 3-SAT in order to prove NP completeness? Why 3-SAT in particular? What do we achieve from doing this? Does it have to do with the fact that 3-SAT is NP-complete and by reducing it to other problems it means that they are also NP-complete?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

We do not always try to reduce from 3-ST in order to prove NP completeness. Sometimes we reduce from other known NP complete problems.

The easiest or most common way to prove that any given problem is NP-complete is to show that it can be reduced to another problem that is already known to be NP-complete. 3-SAT is already proven to be NP-complete and often is a good candidate to reduce another problem to, so it is frequently used in proofs of NP-completeness. Reducing to any other known NP-complete problem would work just as well.
